# Custom TabelViewCell disappears after UITextField in cell becomes first responder

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have been googling for hours now, but can't seem to find anyone with the same issue.

I have a custom cell, with a UIButton and a UITextField connected as IBOutlets in the cell class. In my ViewController I have setup a trailingSwipeAction to present an "edit" button. What I try to accomplish is to after the edit is tapped, I want to set the UITextField on the cell to .becomeFirstResponder() so the user can edit the textfield. And it seems to work perfectly with the below code, but (as showed in the video) 1 sec after it becomes first responder the cell disappears. If I then try to swipe on the empty cell again I get an exception in Xcode:

```
Thread 1: Exception: "Actions view not added to view hierarchy after calling -swipeActionController:insertActionsView:forItemAtIndexPath: on <UITableView: 0x7fab7b827000; frame = (0 20; 414 793); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60000205b870>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002e5d040>; contentOffset: {0, -24}; contentSize: {414, 264}; adjustedContentInset: {24, 0, 0, 0}; dataSource: <FocusOn.TodayController: 0x7fab7ac06730>>"
```

Swipe action in my ViewController:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let swipeAction = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [editContextualAction(forRowAt: indexPath), deleteContextualAction(forRowAt: indexPath)])
    return swipeAction
}

func editContextualAction(forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") {
        (contextualAction: UIContextualAction, swipeButton: UIView, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) in

        let goalCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? GoalTableViewCell

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            goalCell?.goalTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            print(goalCell?.goalTextField.canBecomeFirstResponder) // Returns true
            goalCell?.goalTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }

        completionHandler(true)
    }

    action.backgroundColor = .magenta
    return action
}
```

[image]

If I scroll the tableview afterwards so the empty cell get out of the tableview and back, it returns. (Not seen the the video).

Comment: Hey! Did you manage to figure this one out?

Comment: I refactored a lot of this and it solved it. Not sure exactly what did it. However this becomeFirstResponder definitely seems to cause the problem. :) Do you have a similar problem?

Comment: Yes, I have a similar problem with the cell disappearing if becomeFirstResponder is called before the swipe animation finishes. Worked around it by observing when the animation ends to call becomeFirstResponder